# Save to Android Pay: How to delete a class from Mechant Center

Tags: android, android-pay

I've created couple of test classes in my 'Save to Android Pay' Merchant Center. Now, I'm ready to delete some of them but I can't find that option. I tried to update the class status from `UNDER_REVIEW` to `DRAFT` but I'm getting the following error message:

```
Update failed: Cannot move approved class back to draft
```

Does anyone know a way to delete unneeded classes from the Merchant Center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Save to Android Pay Team, you cannot delete a class from the Merchant Center but only changes its status to `DRAFT`. The failure mentioned in my question is temporary according to Google.

Comment: Did you get any response regarding this question?

Comment: @Marco there is currently no way to delete Google Pay classes.

Comment: Its still impossible to delete a pass class. This is a deal-breaker for my adoption of this service.

Comment: any changes on this topic? still not possible to delete?